# Merge/output Unique values of two CSVs using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to find unique values/merge two CSVs. But it doesn't seem to be working.

For some reason the code doesn't return unique values (doesn't merge). The output is always the values of the first CSV. In this case it's returning the values of `$Users1`. If i change it to `$UserUnique = $Users2 + $user1` it returns the values of `$User2`

Here's my code:

```
$Users1 = Import-Csv -Path \\share\user\Desktop\disabledusers.csv
$Users2 = Import-Csv -Path \\share\user\Desktop\disabledusers2.csv

$UserUnique = $Users1 + $user2
$UserUnique | Select-Object -Property * -Unique
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

My Ref link - [How to merge two csv files in powershell with same headers and discard duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341514/how-to-merge-two-csv-files-in-powershell-with-same-headers-and-discard-duplicate/38342333#38342333)

More information as requested: Please find the CSVs and expected outcome attached below.

$Users1

```
name    lastlogondate   passwordlastset SAMAccountName  
Name1   20/03/2017 12:54    05/09/2013 13:43    Sam1    
Name2   18/08/2016 10:31    04/03/2015 09:42    Sam2    
Name3   11/09/2016 17:48    17/03/2015 12:02    Sam3    
Name4   06/09/2016 08:46    06/10/2015 09:44    Sam4    
Name5   07/09/2016 08:46    07/10/2015 09:44    Sam5    
Name6   08/09/2016 08:46    08/10/2015 09:44    Sam6
```

$Uers2

```
name    lastlogondate   passwordlastset SAMAccountName
Name1   20/03/2017 12:54    05/09/2013 13:43    Sam1
Name2   18/08/2016 10:31    04/03/2015 09:42    Sam2
Name3   11/09/2016 17:48    17/03/2015 12:02    Sam3
Name4   06/09/2016 08:46    06/10/2015 09:44    Sam4
Name7   09/09/2016 08:46    09/10/2015 09:44    Sam7
Name8   10/09/2016 08:46    10/10/2015 09:44    Sam8
Name9   11/09/2016 08:46    11/10/2015 09:44    Sam9
Name10  12/09/2016 08:46    12/10/2015 09:44    Sam10
```

Expected Outcome

```
name    lastlogondate   passwordlastset SAMAccountName
Name1   20/03/2017 12:54    05/09/2013 13:43    Sam1
Name2   18/08/2016 10:31    04/03/2015 09:42    Sam2
Name3   11/09/2016 17:48    17/03/2015 12:02    Sam3
Name4   06/09/2016 08:46    06/10/2015 09:44    Sam4
Name5   07/09/2016 08:46    07/10/2015 09:44    Sam5
Name6   08/09/2016 08:46    08/10/2015 09:44    Sam6
Name7   09/09/2016 08:46    09/10/2015 09:44    Sam7
Name8   10/09/2016 08:46    10/10/2015 09:44    Sam8
Name9   11/09/2016 08:46    11/10/2015 09:44    Sam9
Name10  12/09/2016 08:46    12/10/2015 09:44    Sam10
```

Comment: As per mklement0, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44428189/1701026. But if you looking for a way to join the tables on a common property (please, be more clear and show use a part of the `csv` files), you might want to try [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join/2.2.2/DisplayScript) and do something like `$UserUnique = $Users1 | Join $Users2 -On 'User'` (where `'User'` is the common property name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is a **simple typo**: `$user2` should be `$users2`.

**An undefined variable - `$user2`, in this case - defaults to `$null`**, making the intended array concatenation operation `$Users1 + $user2` a no-op: effectively, you get just `$Users1`, and that explains your symptom (your attempt to swap the operands, `$Users2 + $user1`, preserved the typo).

To prevent such typos, **use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher to make PowerShell report an *error* if an undefined variable is accessed** (except inside `"..."`).

Beyond that, however, I suggest bypassing `Import-Csv` and the costly `Select-Object -Property *` approach (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363570/45375) to the linked question for an explanation), which both simplifies your code and makes it more efficient:

```
Get-Content \\share\user\Desktop\disabledusers.csv, \\share\user\Desktop\disabledusers2.csv |
  Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. Can't believe i made a whole post for a typo. Anyway, Thanks for pointing out and thanks for the tip on set-strictmode. I think that'll help

Comment: @Atheek: No worries - many others didn't spot it either (and it took me a while). It does underscore the importance of an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), however: in the process of constructing one you may actually notice such typos yourself (or at least you'll make it easier for others to spot them).